# Delimit pandas column and store specific values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split, delimiter

I have a situation where I want to delimit a column in a certain manner that only a certain amount if information should be returned. The pandas column has the data in the following format:

```
Turkey (A)- ABC - CDESS - CDS DEE 10. AAAA, || Office 1'
```

and I want only the following from the above :

```
Office 1
```

and this replace has to be applied to every entry in the column.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: so u want just the text after || ? if true, does || appear only once in every text and towards the tail of the text?

Comment: I want the text written just after || without any trailing space

Comment: || only appears once at the same location as I have shown above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas [string extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regex : the regex will search for ||, extract the values and then u can strip off any whitespace.

```
text = 'Turkey (A)- ABC - CDESS - CDS DEE 10. AAAA, || Office 1'
df = pd.DataFrame([text])

df['extract'] = df[0].str.extract(r'((?<=\|\|).*)')
df['extract'] = df['extract'].str.strip()
print(df)

       0                                                extract
0   Turkey (A)- ABC - CDESS - CDS DEE 10. AAAA, ||...   Office 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split()`

```
text = 'Turkey (A)- ABC - CDESS - CDS DEE 10. AAAA, || Office 1'
df = pd.DataFrame([text])
print(df[0].str.split('\|\|', expand=True)[1])

0     Office 1
Name: 1, dtype: object
```